# Selecting clusters below a certain height in a dendrogram R but only if the cluster is bigger than one

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, hclust

I'm looking to write some simple code that will select for certain clusters below a threshold height and highlight them (either with a box or by colour). 
So far I have used cutree, which selects the clusters I am after, but it also selects all the clusters of size 1.

[image: Image of all clusters selected]

I've managed to use which to select the clusters I actually want, but as this is only a very small section of the data I have I don't want to have to go through manually to choose these. Is there a way that I can cut the tree but only select clusters bigger than one?

[image: Image of the wanted clusters selected]

This is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
plot(hClust,hang = -1,cex=0.5)
abline(h= 0.0018,col = 'blue')

ct <- cutree(hClust, h = 0.0018)
clust <- rect.hclust(hClust, h=0.0018, which = c(1,2,4,8,23))
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide your data so I will illustrate with the built-in `mtcars` data. Of course, the heights are different than yours.  Same set-up as your problem:

```
hClust =hclust(dist(mtcars))
plot(hClust,hang = -1, cex=0.8)
abline(h= 28,col = 'blue')
```

[image: First Cutoff]

Now we can call `rect.hclust` without printing (`border=0`), to get the clusters numbered as `rect.hclust` see them. Then we can select the clusters with more than one point and put the boxes around those.

```
clust <- rect.hclust(hClust, h=28, border=0)
NumMemb = sapply(clust, length)
clust <- rect.hclust(hClust, h=28, which=which(NumMemb>1))
```

[image: Boxed tree]